# How do organs grow to the exact shape and size?

Tags: human-biology, gynecology

We all know that organs begin to grow in a foetus around three weeks after fertilization. But how does the body know exactly which shape and size the various organs need to grow to?

Comment: I think this is too broad; you're talking about a whole field of biology ("development") that would be taught across multiple university courses, and the answer won't be quite the same for each organ and can be answered at multiple levels of analysis (e.g., at a systems/overview level, down to individual regulatory genes and products).

Comment: "Organogenesis" might help you in your research. It appears "signalling" is key, but not the only factor.

Comment: other search terms that may help are "developmental biology" Hox genes" "intrinsic regulatory mechanism" and "feedback mechanism" here is an article to start with. https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fcell.2021.820391/full

Comment: The other answers are good. The other part of this answer is that we don't exactly know how it happens in all cases, but we have a lot of knowledge of what influences it.

Comment: Thank you @BigMistake!

Comment: Thank you @BryanKrause!

Comment: Thank you @DKNguyen!

Comment: Thank you @John!